# Conversion of date string and time string into datetime in c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

we have a Data-table with 3 fields Date(string type)(MM/dd/YYYY) Hours(string type)(24 hours format) and minutes(string Type) i need to create a another column that of date time based from the above 3 columns and need to  sort the data table by that date time column

```
Date        Hours   Minutes
5/19/2015   12      30
11/18/2015  23      45
```

I tried to create a string like this  `Date +" "+Hours+":"+ Minutes` and converted to datetime. But I  am getting an error

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

can any help  me  in this issue please

Comment: Why do you store everything as string?

Comment: You just need one field as a `DateTime`. Can we see your work as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate your DataTable and use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with explicit format string, like that:

```
DataTable dt;
foreach (var row in dt.Rows) 
    row["DateTime"]=DateTime.ParseExact(row.Date +" "+row.Hours+":"+ row.Minutes,"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm",null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you store everything as string in the first place? However, you can build the complete DateTime by using `DateTime.TryParseExact`. Then you can  use `Linq-To-DataTable` for the ordering. Finally create the ordered table with `CopyToDataTable`:

```
table.Columns.Add("DateColumn", typeof(DateTime));
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    string dateTimeString = String.Format("{0} {1}:{2}",
        row.Field<string>("Date"),
        row.Field<string>("Hours"),
        row.Field<string>("Minutes"));
    DateTime date;
    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeString, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date));
    {
        row.SetField("DateColumn", date);
    }
}
table = table.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(row => row.Field<DateTime>("DateColumn"))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

So you don't need to store the hours and minutes separately, a `DateTime` stores all informations in one object. Three of your columns in the table are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ParseExact` method. I found it very simple

```
  table.Columns.Add("MixedData",typeof(DateTime));
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
                    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(row["Dates"].ToString() + " " + row["Hours"] + ":" + row["Minutes"], "M/dd/yyyy H:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    row["MixedData"] = date;
                    table.AcceptChanges();
   }
```

Comment: Dear Imadoddin Ibn Alauddin, i tried the way that you suggest but iam getting the same error  "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

Comment: Please check what string you are getting before getting an error

Comment: I am getting the strings like this 5/19/2015 22:30, 5/19/2015 12:00,5/22/2015 23:40

Comment: ok... means the format you provided was wrong because your date is not in MM/dd/yyyy format but in M/dd/yyyy format. So follow edited answer and get back to me if you are facing any other issue.